# Xcode can't find library files when compiling

Tags: c++, xcode

I was trying to use the SFML library to practise c++, so here's what i did in order to link the library:

- I went to Build Settings > Header Search Paths and i inserted the absolute path leading to SFML's include folder.
- Then i went to Build Settings > Library Search Paths and i inserted  the absolute path leading to SFML's lib folder.

When i try to compile it says that the symbols can't be found...
What have i done wrong? isn't this the way you link libraries?

Comment: Have you linked the libraries?

Comment: i'm new to xcode, doesn't adding path to library search path do just that?

Comment: it tells xcode where to look for a library not which libraries to look for

Comment: but how do i do that in xcode i can't seem to find the answer, i went to link libraries with binaries, i selected the dylib file relative to the cpp header file ad it doesn't work.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/5494370